# want to su without password inside shell script

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, sudo, su

I have written a script which will run a script for a backup before:

```
# cat backup-before-shutdown
#Scritp to take backup before shutdown
#Author Ashish Karpe

echo "Taking backup to s3"
su ubuntu /bin/sh /home/ubuntu/backup.sh
/bin/sh /home/ubuntu/backup-to-s3.sh
```

Normally when I switch the user from `root` to `ubuntu` it doesn't ask password as its switching from `root` to `ubuntu` but it's asking while running the script. So what should I do to avoid the password in my script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the script is running as the root user, this `sudo` command string *should* execute the command without requiring a password.

```
sudo -H -u ubuntu /bin/sh /home/ubuntu/backup.sh
```

Comment: +1, and if the script is not runing as the root user, a sudo rule must be added for the user `<user>` to run as user ubuntu with the flag NOPASSWD: `<user> ALL=(ubuntu) NOPASSWD:/bin/sh /home/ubuntu/backup.sh`